# scale down pdf to fit in iframe in uiwebview

Tags: pdf, iframe, uiwebview

I have a uiwebview that loads a iframe to display a pdf file.
But only the top left corner of the pdf file i visible, I need to fit the pdf file inside then iframe, that is, I need to scale down the pdf file so that all of it is visible.
I know that with webpages you can open a pdf and set the starting scale on it like this page1.pdf#zoom=25 but that doesnt work in the webview. Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 3):

try the **scalesPageToFit** property (replace nameOfYourWebview with the actual variable name of your webview

`nameOfYourWebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

You should use the documentation more, there you can easily find things like that. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit